# How can I copy a strided matrix in BLAS?

Tags: matrix, memcpy, blas, cblas

BLAS level 3 Matrix/Matrix routines take arguments `lda`, `ldb` etc. that allow one to pass 'strided' matrices, as far as I understand. For instance, if I have the following 2 x 2 column-major matrix:

```
|1 2|
|3 4|
|x x|
```

where x's are data I want ignored, I can represent this using arguments `m = 2, n = 2, lda=3` (for column major matrices).
My question is, can such matrices be copied using BLAS routines?

If the stride equals the matrix dimension (i.e. the matrix is not strided) it is trivial to use *vector copy* procedure e.g. `dcopy(m*n,A,1,B,1)` to do this. **Is there a way to do this when the matrix elements are not contiguous i.e. lda/stride != m**

One way I can think of doing this is repeatedly calling `dcopy` with increasing offsets, while keeping the `incrx` parameter equal to m. It doesn't seem efficient. Alternatively `dgemm` with B = I and C = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this documentation:

http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/slacpy.f.html

```
SLACPY( UPLO, M, N, A, LDA, B, LDB )
```

The above would do what you want for single precision real matrices from all or part of A into B for example. Its use is fairly strait-forward. Of course you'll find implementations for all flavours D,C,Z

Comment: I've accepted the answer although it's puzzling this is in LAPACK rather than BLAS. There doesn't appear to be the equivalent in BLAS.

Comment: First of all thx. But now to your point: It's true that xLACPY are part of LAPACK. The reason is that they were coded by LAPACK programmers and are LAPACK auxiliary routines. As far as I know, xLACPY was coded to help xHSEQR factorisation drivers. There is a discussion about moving those routines to lower level packages. But so far it has remained a discussion.

Comment: Yes, in the [BLAST forum spec](http://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/) p. 2 it says 
_Many of the new operations are based upon auxiliary routines in LAPACK (e.g. ... GE_COPY). Only after the LAPACK project was begun was it realized that there were operations like matrix copy routine (GE_COPY) .. that ocurred so often that it was wise to make separate routines for them._

But it looks like this spec is not the same as the current ref BLAS implementation. I was puzzled as I couldn't find GE_COPY. This makes sense now.

Comment: Worth mentioning that SLACPY operates on strided, triangular matrices. i.e. not sure how it would work on packed or banded storage.